# MiKTeX Issue (Now using TeXLive)

Tags: miktex

For some reason or the other my MiKTeX binaries aren't being read by Texmaker. Note that in the environment variable path I have the following:

[image]

When I try to compile it uses TeXLive. Why? Anyone else has this issue? Is there a fix for this?

Note that prior to today, it was using MiKTeX.

Comment: Open a command line outside texmaker and one from inside texmaker and check the path with set or echo %path% in both. Check also the option of texmaker.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have check the above and still compiles using TeXLive. Any other suggestion? Thanks by the way.